# Cycle through words on hover with background

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I cycle through a list of words on top of a background image. For example, lets say the phrase is "Hello World" and I want to cycle through a list of the word "hello" in different languages when the phrase is hovered over. How would I do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, add example and share the code you have so far. It is not clear what you are referring to .

Comment: Probably setInterval attached to a variable so you can stop it whenever the mouse leaves the word "hello" and set it to default. Honestly, I would recommend you share your current code with us.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it doesn't really make sense to change "hello" without also changing "world", especially given that in some languages you might need more than two words to say "hello world", and for some the correct word sequence might actually be "world hello".

But ignoring that issue:

```js
var words = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yo", "Aloha", "Bonjour"]
var w = 0
var interval

var container = document.querySelector(".greeting")
var word = container.querySelector("span")

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    word.textContent = words[w = (w + 1) % words.length]
  }, 400)
});
container.addEventListener("mouseout", () => clearInterval(interval))
```

```css
.greeting {
  background-image: url("whatever");
}
```

```html
<div class="greeting"><span>Hello</span> world</div>
```